# Eigenvalues and power of a operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^k$, prove that at least one of the $k^{th}$ roots of $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

I know it is easy to prove when $A$ can be presented by a matrix, but $A$ is an operator on a complex inner product space, which may be infinite dimensional.

Comment: Hint: Being over the field $\mathbb{C}$ is critical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mu_1,...,\mu_k$ be the roots of order $k$ of $\lambda$.

Clearly $\mu_1,...,\mu_k$ are solutions for the polynomial $(x^k-\lambda)$. In particular we have $x^k-\lambda = \prod_{l=1}^k (x-\mu_l)$.

We conclude that $(A^k-\lambda\cdot I) = \prod_{l=1}^{k} (A-\mu^l\cdot I)$.

Can you finish now? (If $\ker(S)=\ker(T)=\{0\}$ what can you say about $\ker(ST)$?)

Comment: Thanks! Ker($ST$) is also {0} so there must be a $\mu_l$ s.t. Ker($A-\mu_l \cdot I$) $\neq$ {0}.

Comment: @Zeng yes, exactly.